# WIn10 wsl2 :Ubuntu getting fatal: unable to access 'https: Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: windows-10, wsl-2

no matter which HTTPS i try to connect in this example i try to clone GitHub repository
I'm getting timeout error :

```
git clone https://github.com/libuv/libuv.git
Cloning into 'libuv'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/libuv/libuv.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

this was not in WSL1
i so allot of suggestions solution but nothing worked out .

Comment: Are you behind any proxy/firewall. Add an exception for bash.exe in your antivirus/ windows firewall

Comment: im only using windows 10 firewall which is tuned off

Comment: Try adding an exception in Windows Security. Firewall is not off by default, are you pretty sure it's off?

Are you behind any network which you don't have admin access to? Or are you using any kind of vpn or something?

Comment: It is off, the thing is that WSL1 worked great, i saw allot of complaints online about this subject

Comment: yeah I saw them too, almost all of them point to a network issue or a core WSL issue. I have never faced this issue even on early WSL days

Comment: I've been having this issue for a very long time now and its still not resolved. Even when someone posts the issue on github they simply mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that applies to your situation. But I fix the issue by turning off mobile hotspot of my laptop.

I am using WSL2 Ubuntu distro and Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867].